# cakePHP working with passwords on updating a record

Tags: cakephp, model

I am using cakePHP 2.0 and am busy with a user management form for my site. The issue is that when I recall the user information row from the database, it reads the password in its ecrypted form and then populates the form element with a long string (I am assuming the encrypted password).

On save, my validation rules break because I limit to 8 characters (which is a good thing because I dont want to save the encrypted version of a password).

I also cannot leave the field blank because it may result in people saving and failing the validation rules again (no password entered)

What is the best way to overcome this? I thought about replacing the row's populated password with an 8 character dummy password and do a validation check, however, that will not work because a) someone MAY use the same password and b) I will need to do another find to get the original password again which does not make sense.

Any help?

```
 // Controller EDIT:
 public function edit($id = null) {
    $this->User->id = $id;
    if(!$this->User->exists()) {
       $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user does not exist'));
       $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    } else {
        if($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
            if($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash('The user has been updated','default',array('class'=>'success'));
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        }
        $this->request->data = $this->User->read(null, $id);
        $userTypes = $this->User->UserType->find("list");
        $userStatuses = $this->User->UserStatus->find("list");
        $this->set(compact("userTypes","userStatuses"));
    }

}

 // HTML Form:
 <?php echo $this->Form->create('User');?>
<fieldset>
    <legend><?php echo __('Modify User '); ?></legend>
    <h3><?php echo $this->Html->link("Return to user index",array("controller" => "users","action" => "index")); ?></h3>
<?php
    echo $this->Form->input('username');
    echo $this->Form->input('password',array("id" => "profilePassword","empty" => true, "autocomplete" => "off"));
    echo $this->Form->input('company');
    echo $this->Form->input('first_name');
    echo $this->Form->input('last_name');
    echo $this->Form->input('telephone');
    echo $this->Form->input('fax');
    echo $this->Form->input('user_status_id');
    echo $this->Form->input('user_type_id');
?>
</fieldset>
 <?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Update'));?>
```

Comment: why are you opening the same question again you asked earlier? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11598422/cakephp-pre-populates-password-field-and-breaks-on-update => also, you already got your answer on how to make it work properly. And last but not least there are at least 5 other questions like this, all answered. it is pretty much an exact duplicate of any of them. just google it.

Comment: If I wanted a tutorial from another site I wouldn't ask the question on stackoverflow. Support on that site is a bit cocky. thanks.

Comment: it is still an exact duplicate of your previous one. also: you seem to be pretty reluctant in learning not only from your mistakes but also from help from others. no help from me anymore, thats for sure.

Comment: That would be a blessing kind sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should unset password if it's empty (user didn't wanted to change it)

before you save your model try:

```
if(empty($this->request->data[$this->alias]['password'])) {
    unset($this->request->data[$this->alias]['password']);
}
```

this way if user wants to change the password it will be validated, and if he doesn't change it it will not update and will pass validation. You also can not require password field in validation rules or it will never pass in case user don't change the password. Instead set rules like length limit ect...

Comment: Hi @rene, no it actually didn't - only because there was a closing bracket missing from the first line of code, which I popped in. It's also better practice to use $this->alias rather than the Model name here. I included that update as stackoverflow requires a minimum of 4 character changes to allow an edit (and adding a single bracket isn't enough, even when it's required).

Answer (score 0):

specify fields that you want to retrieve in your find calls through fields array in params, simply dont fetch password field, this will not populate password field in form and there would be no need to unset request variables.

Further if you dont want to do what i said above, do specify the name of fields in your Model::save() call, simple dont put password field in fields array.